# Переменная для расчета вхождения в промежуток времени

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день.

Просьба помочь разобраться в синтаксисе: выводятся активности (*act4.activity_memo*) и их продолжительности (*act4.activity_duration*) в промежутке времени с 0 до 7 часов утра. Необходимо, чтобы активности, находящиеся на границе времени, например в 6 начинается и в 11 заканчивается отображалась только с промежутком времени до 7 утра - то есть будет указано 1 час продолжительности.

```
DECLARE
@sum_dur float = 0 *объявляем переменную для накопления сумм*

SELECT cast(act4.activity_memo as nvarchar(max))+ ' - ' + cast(ROUND(
(@sum_dur = @sum_dur + act4.activity_duration *суммируем продолжительности*
case
    when @sum_dur <= 7 then act4.activity_duration
    when @sum_dur > 7 then act4.activity_duration - @sum_dur - 7
end
),2) as nvarchar(max)) + 'ч.' + char(10) + ';'
    FROM DM_ACTIVITY act4
    WHERE act4.daily_id = DM_DAILY.daily_id AND DATEPART(HOUR,act4.time_to) >= 0 AND DATEPART(HOUR,act4.time_from) <= 6 *только активности с 0 до 7 утра*
    ORDER BY act4.time_from ASC *сортировка по времени начала*
```

Comment: Вы почему то сравниваете с 7 суммарную продолжительность. Судя по всему вам требуется брать семь минус время начала и выдавать это число в случае, если оно меньше, чем текущая продолжительность. Если это число отрицательно (время начала более 7 утра) - выводить 0. И совершенно не ясно, зачем вы используете переменную, чего вы пытаетесь достичь с ее помощью. Вам нужны результаты вычисленные только по текущей строке или кумулятивная сумма от начала выборки

Comment: К сожалению, выявляются проблемы с манипуляциями с датой. И хотелось бы уйти от оперирования датами в SQL, в пользу числового значения продолжительности операции.

Comment: Так про продолжительность никто и не говорит, оставляйте ее числом. Но если по условиям задачи "от 0 до 7 утра" то вы от даты начала операции и манипуляции с ней никуда не уйдете. Час то надо выделить из нее

Comment: Я вот думала это из продолжительности сделать. А то у меня выходит страшная штука)))

Comment: case
when DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, act4.time_to, 0), act4.time_to) <= '1900-01-01 07:00:00' and DATEPART(dd,act4.time_from) = DATEPART(dd,act4.time_to) then act4.activity_duration
when DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, act4.time_to, 0), act4.time_to) > '1900-01-01 07:00:00' or DATEPART(dd,act4.time_from) <> DATEPART(dd,act4.time_to) then 7 - DATEPART(HOUR,act4.time_from) - (DATEPART(MINUTE,act4.time_from) / 60.)
end

Comment: И это только от 0-7 утра.

Comment: Оригинальное конечно условие DATEPART(dd,act4.time_from) <> DATEPART(dd,act4.time_to), оно же никогда не выполняется :) И непонятно зачем сложные конструкции с datediff есть есть datepart (хотя в MS SQL2005 его быть не дложно)

Comment: DATEPART(dd,act4.time_from) <> DATEPART(dd,act4.time_to) - это очень важная штука, до которой я дошла не сразу. В текущей базе если операция на начало суток имеет дату-время 01.01.2016 00:00:00, а операция на конец суток дату и время окончания 02.01.2016 00:00:00.

Comment: С датами очень громоздко получается. Как с переменной правильно синтаксис сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Как минимум вместо второго when и кучи условий вы можете написать единственное слово `else`

Comment: И все таки надо бы уточнить условия задачи. При ваших текущих условиях, если работа начнется в 00:00 и закончится в 07:00 то будет честно засчитано 7 часов. Но если она начнется в 23:59 и закончится в 06:59 другого дня то `7-23-59/60`, т.е. где то минус 17 часов. А что если работа продолжает 2е суток, и в обоих есть ночной интервал, то надо считать оба интервала или только из первого дня или только из второго. И вы приводите примеры только с часами, минуты то надо учитывать или нет. И если надо, то в часах и десятичных долях часа или часах и минутах